# Is it possible to make component style dependent on state without re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs

I am working with the component below - I need the button to be contained when the filter state corresponds to it and outlined otherwise.

The way I do it now, the component re-renders every time the state is changed - I see why this is happening. However, I wonder if there would be a way to achieve the same functionality without referring to the `filter` state in this component? It is not a great user experience if the buttons disappear every time the state changes.

```
function FilterButtons({ filter, setFilter }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.heroButtons}>
      <Grid container spacing={2} justify="center">
        <Grid item>
          <Button
            variant={filter === "All" ? "contained" : "outlined"}
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => setFilter("All")}
          >
            All
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Button
            variant={filter === "Blue" ? "contained" : "outlined"}
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => setFilter("Blue")}
          >
            Blue
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Button
            variant={filter === "Red" ? "contained" : "outlined"}
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => setFilter("Red")}
          >
            Red
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Button
            variant={filter === "Green" ? "contained" : "outlined"}
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => setFilter("Green")}
          >
            Green
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: "It is not a great user experience if the buttons disappear every time the state changes." - why are your buttons disappearing?

Comment: The button shouldn't be disappearing on filter state change only the style should change. how do you render the FilterButton component. Could you show its parent too

Comment: Actually when you set the filter, the parent re-renders and so your component must do

Comment: Isn't it correct that the component re-renders when a piece of state that is used by it changes?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at styled components. This is exactly what you're describing in your question. You can pass a props to a styled components and it will use this props to update its style without rendering.